# NameNotFoundException Java Enterprise Application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jndi, jboss-4.2.x

I am working on a Java Enterprise application which have an EJB layer and a WEB layer bundled together with an EAR. The problem I am facing is that I have some entities in my EJB layer and when I try to get their EAOs by JNDI in my WEB layer, I get NameNotFoundException.

My Ear name is : **StudentManagement**

My EJB layer is : **StudentManagementEJB**

My Web layer is : **StudentManagementWEB**

Application Server : **JBOSS-4.2**

**My Entity Class :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="student_id")
private int studentId;

@Column(name="sudent_name")
private String studentName;

@Column(name="student_class")
private String studentClass;

public int getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}

public String getStudentClass() {
    return studentClass;
}

public void setStudentClass(String studentClass) {
    this.studentClass = studentClass;
}
}
```

**My Remote Inteface :**

```
@Remote
public interface StudentEAO {

public void save(Student student);

}
```

**My Interface Implementation:**

```
@Stateless
public class StudentEAOImpl implements StudentEAO {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.learn.interfce.StudentEAO#save(com.learn.entity.Student)
 */
@Override
public void save(Student student) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        entityManager.persist(student);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

**And In my servlet, I am trying to get StudentEAOImpl  Object as**

```
   try {
        StudentEAO studentEao = (StudentEAO) new InitialContext().lookup("StudentManagement/StudentEAOImpl/remote");
        studentEao.save(student);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**StackTrace of ERROR :**

```
01:15:45,539 INFO  [STDOUT] Hello World from StudentActionServlet.
01:15:45,543 ERROR [STDERR] javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: StudentManagement not bound
01:15:45,543 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:529)
01:15:45,543 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:537)
01:15:45,543 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:543)
01:15:45,543 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:267)
01:15:45,543 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:628)
01:15:45,543 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:590)
01:15:45,543 ERROR [STDERR] at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
01:15:45,543 ERROR [STDERR] at com.learn.servlets.StudentActionServlet.doGet(StudentActionServlet.java:46)
```

I am not getting what I am missing here. Please help me in this regard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlast! Issue resolved and here are my findings about that:

1- You have to check your EJB, WEB and EAR layer compiler level, It all should be same.

2- Check your EAR name while giving JNDI name , means if your JNDI name is : MyEar/MYEJB/remote, then MyEar should be your EA-Project name.

3- You server log must be clean. It should not produce any critical exception which may be show-stopper.

After doing all these checks and fixes, my issue is resolved.
Hopefully it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind your EAOImpl class manually as follows:

@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding="StudentManagement/StudentEAOImpl/remote")